# OpenSSL private key read error(PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl

I am trying to read a PrivateKey by openSSL and VC++, I am getting this error "`OpenSSL error: error:0906D064:lib(9):func(109):reason(100)`"..

My Private Key :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

My Code :

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    BIO *mem = NULL; 
    RSA *rsa_private = NULL;
    char *private_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\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\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    mem = BIO_new_mem_buf(private_key, strlen(private_key));
    if (mem == NULL) 
    { 
        char buffer[120]; 
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer); 
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenSSL error: %s", buffer);
        exit(0);
    } 

    rsa_private = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(mem, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
    BIO_free (mem); 
    if (rsa_private == NULL) 
    { 
        char buffer[120]; 
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer); 
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenSSL error: %s", buffer);
        exit(0);
    } 

    return(0);

}
```

I am using WinXP-SP2 and MS-Visual Studio 2008..
I am getting error in this line : `rsa_private = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(mem, NULL, NULL, NULL);`
Error : (`OpenSSL error: error:0906D064:lib(9):func(109):reason(100)`)

Any one can help me, how should I read this privet key ????

Thanks.....

Comment: @Raj: From the syntax point of view, it seems fine. Try to read the key from file using PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey and passing FILE pointer to this function. If it works, then there must be some problem with buffer. To verify that certificate in file is correct, open it in Certificate snap-in. If it is opened properly, then means file is okay.

Comment: Please check if adding new lines'\n' says after every 64th character helps you.

Comment: Your buffer is not the exact representation of the file which you pasted here.

Comment: I tried that exact code (except that I'm using `const char* private_key`, but that shouldn't matter) and it's working fine...

Answer (score 3):

The variable `private_key` is initialized wrongly. You need to add `\n` after each line in your Private Key.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
unsigned char *rsaPrivateKeyChar = (unsigned char *)key.c_str();
// write char array to BIO
BIO *rsaPrivateBIO = BIO_new_mem_buf(rsaPrivateKeyChar, -1);
// create a RSA object from private key char array
RSA *rsaPrivateKey = NULL;
PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(rsaPrivateBIO, &rsaPrivateKey, NULL, NULL);
return rsaPrivateKey;
```

Comment: while creating rsaPrivateBIO, why did you take length -1?

Comment: AkashToSky: I think it works out that if -1 is supplied, then it will do strlen()  on the 1st parameter to work out the length